# dropdown checkbox list html

Tags: html

I have a requirement where in i wish to display a dropdown box when i click in a textbox.... Scenario is.... When i click in the textbox, there should be a list of checkboxes corresponidng to some values.... Whichever checkbox i click on, the correspoding value should get appeneded in the textbox... I tried to google this... But unable to find any solution...

Comment: are you looking for a javascript solution? Tag it as javascript, if so.

Comment: I cannot fully make sense of your description. You want to display a dropdown box upon clicking within the text box --> where should this dropdown box be? When you click in the text box there should be a list of checkboxes --> wait, a dropdown list with checkboxes? Is this a second list which should be displayed next to the dropdown box? When you click on one of the checkboxes its values will be appended to the textbox? How so? Value1,Value2 Or should the values of the checkbox be added to the dropdown box?

Comment: it is just a dropdown list... with multiple selects.... and this select should happen with checkboxes...

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.... there is jquery plugin called dropdownchecklist.... It performs the function as desired...